# jQuery syntax issue with a looping function

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a bit of quick advice on the way to run the following code.

What I need is a button called #p12-1 which (when clicked) will run some functions. When clicked again run some more functions. I'm guessing for this I will need a variable to count which click it is on but I'm not too sure. Please find below my HTML/jQuery.

```
$section == (parseInt(1));

$("#p12-1").click(function ()   {
    if ($section == 1)  {
        var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);        
        //Example Function
                $("#p12-2").fadeOut(1000);
        //End example function 
    };
    if ($section == 2)  {
        var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
        //Example Function
                $("#p12-2").fadeOut(1000);
        //End example function              
    };
    if ($section == 3)  {
        var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
        //Example Function
                $("#p12-2").fadeOut(1000);
        //End example function              
    };
    if ($section == 4)  {
        var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);
        //Example Function
                $("#p12-2").fadeOut(1000);
        //End example function                          
    };
});

        <div class="main-slide main-slide-12" style="display:none;">
            <div id="p12-1" style="display:none;"><img src="images/p12-1.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:block;" id="p12-2"><img src="images/p12-2.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:block;" id="p12-3"><img src="images/p12-3.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-4"><img src="images/p12-4.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-5"><img src="images/p12-5.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-6"><img src="images/p12-6.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-7"><img src="images/p12-7.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-8"><img src="images/p12-8.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-9"><img src="images/p12-9.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-10"><img src="images/p12-10.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-11"><img src="images/p12-11.png" /></div>
            <div style="display:none;" id="p12-12"><img src="images/p12-12.png" /></div>
        </div>
```

The following code doesnt appear to work, how can I fix it?

Comment: Where are you assigning the currentValue variable in this code?

Comment: At the top with this "$section == (parseInt(1));", then on each click section it should add 1 to this value

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. When you click it the first time you want what to happen? When you click it the second time what happens?

Comment: I was trying to only show the code i had to so i took out the functions it would run. But where it says //Example function it will run a series of hiding div's and shows others

Comment: Note: don't call your variable `$section` (with a dollar) unless it represents a jquery oject, otherwise it is confusing. Call it something like `sectionNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `$section = 1` outside of your event binding. But then inside the bound event you redeclare `var $section = (parseInt(currentValue) + 1);` This redeclares the variable into the local scope. You can simplify this a lot

```
var $section = 1;
$("#p12-1").click(function () { 
   $section++; //increment section
   if ($section == 1) {
     //do some stuff
   }
   if ($section == 2) {}
});
```

If you really want to do it this way then you should consider using a switch statement instead of if's.